How would one go about "sampling" the IR of mouth cavity? I.E. formant
Been a little too intrigued with the idea of playing back a portion of a track using my phone (or any other small but strong speaker) holding it next to my mouth and changing the shape/ formant to get a cool sounding filter.
Would be a pain to have to do this everytime, so I figure maybe using a convolution plugin or other (have been working on convolution in reaktor but it's still work in progress), and record the IR using either an impulse, or Sinesweep. How would one go about creating a morphing formant shape from vowel to vowel rather than a single/instantaneous shape from an impulse? From what I've read, realtime modulation/morphing of convolution isn't feasible, when wanting to change the IR over time.
I feel like being able to get any shape/morph from an actual IR of the mouth cavity would be less restricting than using traditional formant filters (more variation). I can't seem to figure it out. Appologies for my lackluster terminology, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm not into articulatory synthesis, so consider this a very armchair question, but: for what reasons are things supposed to not be realtime feasible? A lot of research on speech synthesis through the simulation of the human voice track stems from the late 60s, 70s, and early 80s; so things that were infeasible computationally would be trivial today. However, if "infeasible" means "because mathematically impossible", then that remains true.

//"Been a little too intrigued with the idea of playing back a portion of a track using my phone (or any other small but strong speaker) holding it next to my mouth and changing the shape/ formant to get a cool sounding filter."// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - I did that with the dial tone and telephone receiver when I was a kid.  I thought it was so cool.  Those two tones weren't perfectly sinusoidal, you could really hear the harmonics getting filtered.  A decade later we would see Peter Frampton doing it with a "Talkbox" and a tube going into his mouth.

The easiest way to get something going would be to build a set of 2 or 3 cascaded time variant parametric EQs to model the first two or three formant. The center frequencies are determined by the formant frequencies and you probably have to eyeball the level and the Q by looking at a few vowel spectral and experimenting a bit.
The tricky part may be manage the transitions without artifacts. There are multiple ways of doing this, but the best depends on your specific requirements
Some sources:

A gentle introduction into formants: https://corpus.eduhk.hk/english_pronunciation/index.php/2-2-formants-of-vowels/
A fun one with an actual physical model: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyQ96oerZEs
Good source for parametric EQs: https://www.w3.org/TR/audio-eq-cookbook/


The Wikipedia articles are good.  But your gentle intro link is better.
